# PCI Compliance - Is it necessary to encrypt expiration date if a token is received instead of actual account number? Should the token be encrypted?

Tags: pci-compliance

In our setup, we are receiving a token for the primary account number (PAN), expiration date, and some other information.  We need to save this information into our database.  Is it necessary/recommended to encrypt the expiration date if the we are not getting the actual PAN?  Does the token itself need to be encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

The token is already meaningless, so encrypting it seems an overkill.

**Edit**

Just looked up the [PCI DSS 3.0 Quick Ref.](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI%20SSC%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf) and here's what it says:

> Merchants and any other service providers involved with payment card
>   processing must never store sensitive authentication data after
>   authorization. This includes sensitive data that is printed on a card,
>   or stored on a card’s magnetic stripe or chip – and personal
>   identification numbers entered by the cardholder.

Looks like you need to discard the info rather than encrypt it.

Comment: That statement seems to contradict what appears on page 15 of the document. If you do not save the PAN, then you should be able to save the expiration date. And it does not need to be unreadable...

Comment: That being said, that document is from 2010... (see page 2)

Answer (score 1):

According to the PCI/DSS standards encryption actually has almost no value as it doesn't take anything out of scope. Not to say you shouldn't be encrypting data, but doing so really has virtually no effect on the PCI/DSS question.